# Regex matches one string but fails same

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to use `regex` in `java` to extract some information out of strings. For demo, I have the following (seemingly stupid code):

```
Pattern featureIndexValuePattern = Pattern.compile("([\\w_ \\-\\.\\=]+)\\s+(\\d+)");


String str = "member_currentCompany9042547 0";

String str1 = "member_currentCompany9042547 0";

Matcher match = featureIndexValuePattern.matcher(str);

if (match.find()) {
    System.out.println("FOUND!");
    System.out.println(match.group(0));
    System.out.println(match.group(1));
    System.out.println(match.group(2));
}

match = featureIndexValuePattern.matcher(str1);

if (match.find()) {
    System.out.println("FOUND!");
    System.out.println(match.group(0));
    System.out.println(match.group(1));
    System.out.println(match.group(2));
}
```

The output I get is

```
FOUND!
9042547 0
9042547
0
FOUND!
member_currentCompany9042547 0
member_currentCompany9042547
0
```

Actually the two input strings are exactly same, except the first one is copy-pasted from a file and the latter is hard-coded. I am unable to find why the outputs are different. I suspect it is the character encoding. Could someone help me understand what's happening here?

Thanks,
Nikhil

Comment: Try printing `str.equals(str1)`. There might be a difference in e.g. non-printing spaces, non-breaking whitespace etc. And if they're not equal, print `Arrays.toString(str.toCharArray())` and the same for `str1` to see the difference more easily.

Comment: I get [identical results using your code](https://ideone.com/dRYdvg).

Comment: `str.equals(str1)` returns `false`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, you may get identical results if you copy-pasted the buffer. I am not sure if the char encoding is being preserved all along.

Comment: My suggestion is that, just copy the whole code from here and try to execute in a new java file

Comment: You have a garbled char before `9` in the first string. It is a `\u0001` control char. So, what do you plan now?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am fine accepting unicode control characters and have added \p{C} in the pattern. I am open to, if you have a better suggestion?

Comment: @AndyTurner, your suggestion helped :).

Comment: Right now, I'd just use `s.split("\s+")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following `Andy Turner`'s suggestion in the comments, when performed

```
Arrays.toString(str.toCharArray())
```

I could see the non-printing unicode character (before 9):

```
 str: [m, e, m, b, e, r, _, c, u, r, r, e, n, t, C, o, m, p, a, n, y, , 9, 0, 4, 2, 5, 4, 7,  , 0]
 str1: [m, e, m, b, e, r, _, c, u, r, r, e, n, t, C, o, m, p, a, n, y, 9, 0, 4, 2, 5, 4, 7,  , 0]
```

Adding `\\p{C}` to pattern resolved the issue.

Nikhil